# cts:uris score-random option does not returned random URIs

Tags: random, xquery, marklogic

In the `cts:uris` function I added `"score-random"` to the option of the query but it returns the same results.

Here's my sample query

```
cts:uris("",("score-random"), cts:collection-query('my-collection')) [1 to 10]
```

In contrast to cts:search which returns random results

```
cts:search(collection("my-collection"), cts:and-query(()), ("score-random"))[1 to 10] ! document-uri(.)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
cts:uris("",("score-random","sample=10"), cts:collection-query('my-collection'))
```

Basically use `"sample=10"` instead of `[1 to 10]`.

The `cts:uris()` function always returns its URIs sorted alphabetically, ascending or descending.  Here I'm asking for a random sampling of 10 to be returned, which are then returned alphabetically.

Want the ten returned to be in random order?

```
for $uri in cts:uris("",("score-random","sample=10"), cts:collection-query('my-collection'))
order by xdmp:random()
return $uri
```

(Using the technique from my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42262954/538697)